# Newbie: Reading sys.modules

Tags: python-2.7, python-module

IN https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html, reference is made to sys.modules. I would like to see (print on screen) which modules are listed in sys.modules. How can I do this? I'm using Python2.7 and have only just started.

Comment: `import sys; dir (sys.modules)`

Answer (score 1):

`sys.modules` for read access conforms standard dict protocol.

You may easily do it in REPL, where last mentioned value is printed in P phase:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules
{...}
```

Or you can access it like any other dictionary in actual *.py file:

```
for key in sys.modules:
    print(key, sys.modules[key])

# or
print(sys.modules)
```